# Choosing the right stabilizer / Voltage Regulator for Laptop Charge carts (40 capacity)

Tags: voltage

A client has a laptop charge cart rated input @ 125VAC & output also @ 125VAC. Total 1875 Watts. 
specs: http://www.v7world.com/us/products/charge-carts/charge-cart-30-devices.html#horizontalTab5
their building have only 220V power outlets. So they are planning to use a stabilizer rated @ 3000W link. http://www.stac-japan.jp/high_power/
but in the spec sheet it says that if input  is 220V & device ouput is 110V, will it work properly since there is 15V difference. Also if output is 110V the total watts consumed will be half i.e 1500VA. will it damaged the charge cart. The supplier recommended us to use the 5000W Stabilizer, so output  will be 2500VA. any ideas how to select the corrector voltage regulator?
specs for stabilizer on page 4: http://progressive.net.pk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/stac.pdf

Comment: Seems like a waste of time and money if all mobile chargers are universal.  I would not use the stabilizer and have a ICL inrush current limiter instead as the surge load will likely be 10x the rated load.  hence, bad plan.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 - Hi, Regarding "*waste of time and money if all mobile chargers are universal*" FYI when I researched the OP's [original question, now deleted, on this topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/365995), the service manual for that "laptop charge cart" shows it contains parts which could be voltage-sensitive. The user manual definitely states to use 120V 15A outlet *only*. Everything you say about universal PSUs is, of course correct. But could those voltage-sensitive devices inside the cart be modified to run on 220V? Unknown - insufficient info in the manuals :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your plan.
[image]
[image]

### My advice

1. Do not use the plan to get a power stabilizer
2. Modify power bars with 0.5A NTC ICL inrush current limiting per outlet
3. Install a line 15A 240Vac filter, 350V MOV OVP,
4. Consider an inexpensive current  meter per power strip,

   - Advantages of ICL over Voltage stabilizer.
   - power cycling surge currents may cause premature wear from high inrush
   - possible nuicance false trips
   - localized light flicker when turned on
   - possible datacomm or computer glitches from inrush EMI.

### Reasons for Eliminating Stabilizer

All modern mobile chargers are universal at least 100~240Vac 50/60Hz or more.

### modifications

Instead modify PDU to have 0.5A /240Vac ICL's soldered in series with each line. Inquire with supplier how to perform this.  0.$25 parts.

Manufacturer    Cantherm    ( or equiv )
Manufacturer Part Number    [***MF72-033D7***](http://www.cantherm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/MF72_JUNE_2016_1.pdf)
Description     ICL 33 OHM 20% 500MA 9MM
 20 ohm cold <4 ohm hot. <9mm x 5mm

Or get a variety and label the outlets for <65W , <120W, <180W and choose two  or three 0.3A , 0.5A and 0.7A  ( needs recalc)

[image]

### What I would do.

1. Find every possible peripheral load
2. Most will be 19~20V <4.5A standard barrel jack and 5V 2.4A   USB,Lightning and Android mobile types.
3. Use 5A polyfuse on each port. with hardwired ports to PSU
4. Use 3 centralized PSU's Meanwell 1kW 240Vac 19~20Vdc supplies
5. Make a PDU with DC cordsets and 6 port 2.4A USB charger ports.
6. Then users do not need to lug around their chargers.
7. Optional to consider a rack to secure each laptop with personal keylock.
8. 240Vac power bar for the oddball units rated for 100~240Vac only but not compatible with above.

[image]

Est. Cost ~ $200.    10 port USB hub $40
[image]

Comment: On page 16 in the user manual, it says that: 
If this product is misused, incorrectly operated or repaired, the warranty will be void. http://www.v7world.com/us/downloads/dl/file/id/1886/product/4810/charge_cart_user_manual.pdf. Since this process is modifying components, so warranty will be not be void right?

Comment: That's why you shud follow my advice and  *Inquire with supplier how to perform this*, which I could do, but not my purview..